# Including script in HTML and attempting to call function in jQuery — no logs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I'm trying to make make an include of `html2canvas` and `jQuery` screenshot the div `#trump`. When calling the `html2canvas` functions in the `my.js` file, there is no output whatsoever in the console which leads to me being unable to find the bug :(

Here is my `head` in `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Here is `my.js`:

```
function export(){ 
document.getElementById('trump').parentNode.style.overflow = 'visible'; //might need to do this to grandparent nodes as well, possibly.
    html2canvas( [ document.getElementById('trump') ], {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.getElementById('trump').parentNode.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=800, height=800");
            $(document).append(canvas);
            //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
        }
     });
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submitter').click(function () {
        var but = $('#submitter');
        but.text('Hi!');
        export();
    }); 
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! There is no output in the console but all of the files look like they are showing up correctly within Chrome dev tools. The `defer` tag was added afterwards as an attempt to fix but no cheerios.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a syntax error here: `$(document).append(icanvas;` is missing the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Hey @SurrealDreams! I just fixed that but even then it did not show any errors. Would you know what the cause to that is? When I look at `my.js` in the Sources section, the `export()` function is nowhere to be seen whereas the other code is showing up fine

Comment: Since JavaScript in interpreted, you may not see an error unless the code is executed.  I'm thinking the click handler on `#submitter` is never being triggered (and so neither is `export()`).  I can't say much more without more code or context.

Comment: The code is being triggered because the button text is changing, but it doesn't look like the `export()` in the trigger is even showing up in the sources for the file. http://fakedonald.online/ if that helps @SurrealDreams

Comment: Just to add, it looks like `export()` was a predetermined function so it was trying to override. It has been solved now and I am seeing the errors! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `export()` function was predetermined which was why it was not being called